# Wordpress & MDPF include external php file template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, mpdf

I am using mpdf for the first time and have integrated it with Wordpress. I have it currently set up in the functions.php file writing out the html but i would like to use a seperate php file as the template for the pdf, is this possible? I can't find anything in the mpdf documentation.

Here is my code so far:

```
add_action('init', 'congres_redirect');

function congres_redirect() {
  if(isset($_GET['offer'])) {
    $restName = get_field('restaurant_name', $post->ID);
      view_conferinta();

  }
}
function view_conferinta() {
$post_id = false; // current post
$output = '<html>
<head><title>Voucher Download</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
<style>
body {
font-family: open sans, san-serif;
}
.voucher {
padding: 20px;
}

</style>
<body>';

 $output .= ' 

 <div class="voucher-content">
    <div class="inner-voucher">
        <h1>Voucher Title</h1>
        <p>Voucher Description</p>
        <p>Voucher Code: EL-200DEG07022020-123AB</p>
    </div>
 </div>


 ';


//$output .='<div class="voucher">Restaurant Name: '.$restName.'</div>';   
$output .= ' 
</body>
</html>';


require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
$mpdf->Output('my-voucher.pdf','I');
//$mpdf->Output($pdfheader.'.pdf', 'D');
exit;
}
```

Comment: If the library doesn’t explicitly offer that as an option - then use what you already have, `$mpdf->WriteHTML($output);` - and find a way to load the contents (or rendered output, if it needs to be dynamic) of your template file into a variable first.

Answer (score 0):

That is something weird...
But it is possible..you need to put your template file into theme for security purpose.
Then you need to get that file contents and use it as out put of your pdf.

```
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template.php';
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($contents);
$mpdf->Output('my-voucher.pdf','I');
//$mpdf->Output($pdfheader.'.pdf', 'D');
exit;
```

Comment: Simply reading the file contents will not be enough, if the template itself has coding inside. (And seeing that there is `$output .='<div class="voucher">Restaurant Name: '.$restName.'</div>'` in the code that was shown, though commented out for now, I think it is safe to assume that eventually it will include stuff like this.)

Comment: @04FS  I put my HTML content with YOUR TAG and its look fine.

Comment: Yes, for static content it will work. But most likely they do _not_ want a completely static template here, but dynamically insert data into it.

Comment: Dear I saw static content that is why I put this code...If content will go dynamic then code would be different.

Comment: If i wanted to include dynamic content how would I go about that, I currently have it set static whilst I test but I would like to add dynamic content at a later date. Thanks

Comment: @Jay you need to put some unique identifiers in your template file like "##VOUCHER TITLE##" and then replace them with your desired value.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me it results in the following errors?

Warning: require(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\\my-path\functions.php on line 397

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '1' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\my-path\functions.php on line 397

When I try to echo the the $filename I just get 1. Any ideas?